# IR2110 LTspice high-side switching problem

Tags: power-electronics, ltspice, simulation, gate-driving, bootstrap

I am working on a half-bridge simulation in LTspice. For the gate drive circuit I am working with an IR2110. My problem is that whatever I select Vin to be above 200 V output, it can't pass 200 V.

I am attaching output voltage waveform for the case where Vin is 300 V. I think the problem is that the high-side switch can't turn on fully. I am attaching the high-side switch DS voltage in the 2nd picture. Any suggestion?

[image: Output Voltage]

[image: HIGH SIDE Vds]

[image: LtSpice SCH]

Comment: I can't find your diode. Is it clamping at 200 V reverse voltage by any chance?

Comment: It's a classic, designers way oversize the bootstrap capacitor. Its value depends on the charge evacuated cycle-by-cycle to bias the high-side transistor. It is usually 100 nF, not 15 µF which could not be properly charged in a real circuit. Same for the gate-source resistance which serve for safety but absorb current. Increase them to 22 or 47k, it's good enough. Don't forget to add deadtime for the input clocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My problem is that whatever I select Vin to be above 200 V output, it
> can't pass 200 V*

The absolute maximum reverse voltage rating for the bootstrap diode ([RF081L2S](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/rf081l2s-243023.pdf)) is 200 volts. That's your problem: -

[image]

Comment: Yes sir. I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: I got zero hits for "DRF081L2S". What was the secret google-fu to remove the D?

Comment: @winny correct.

Comment: How did you come up with it? Removing PBF or packaging information as a suffix is given, but how did you come up with D being a prefix to be removed?

Comment: I remembered using a diode beginning with "RF" and thought I'd try it @winny

Comment: Can't beat straight up experience.

Comment: More luck than anything else @winny